# Game theory question- no idea how to proceed

Tags: game-theory, economics

A monopolist sells two products, X and Y . There are three
consumers with asymmetric preferences. Each consumer buys either
one unit of a product or does not buy the product at all. The per-unit
maximum willingness to pay of the consumers is given in the table
below.

[image]

The monopolist who wants to maximize total payoffs has three alternative
marketing strategies: (i) sell each commodity separately and so charge a
uniform unit price for each commodity separately (simple monopoly
pricing); (ii) offer the two commodities for sale only in a package
comprising of one unit of each, and hence charge a price for the whole
bundle (pure bundling strategy), and (iii) offer each commodity separately
as well as a package of both, that is, offer unit price for each commodity
as well as charge a bundle price (mixed bundling strategy). However, the
monopolist cannot price discriminate between the consumers. Given the
above data, find out the monopolist’s optimal strategy and the
corresponding prices of the products.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Let's use strategy ii. 
Let price of X be 4, price of Y be 4 and bundle X and Y be 6.
Every consumer is paying his maximum, therefore you are winning the maximum.